# Compare two strings in JS to see if the first big string contains exact same match or not

Tags: javascript

I want to compare the following two variables to see if they match exactly or not.
What I am doing right now is:

```
var string1 = "S1";
var string2 = "LS1 B26 M90";

let result = string2.indexOf(string1);
```

It returns 1 which means S1 exists in string2. I want it to look for "S1" and not to match with "LS1".

Comment: Compare strings for exact match with `===`.

Comment: @0stone0 how would that make a difference according to what's asked in the question?

Comment: @Pointy As usual, when posters say "exact match" they mean "match whole word".

Comment: Misread, thought he wanted to check if it contains S1

Comment: Use a regular expression with word boundaries: `\bS1\b`. Or split the string into words, and check if the array contains `S1`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply achive by below:

```
String("LS1 B26 M90").split(" ").includes("LS1")
```

- String("LS1 B26 M90").split(" "): convert string into string list.
- .includes("LS1"): will check the existence it return true in case of
  match otherwise false.

Comment: This seems to work in my case. Thanks for help.

Comment: mark as answer so helpful to comminity